# How should I play wiith White and Black in the Sicilian Dragon?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense

How should I play with White and Black in the Sicilian Dragon?

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 g6 6. Be3 Bg7
```

Comment: This is too broad. People have written whole volumes on this subject!

Comment: Try to make the question more specific to one particular variation of the Sicilian Dragon and perhaps just for one side.

Comment: @Wes, I think "too broad" is a bit harsh. There two main variations down the road one that involves white playing `Bc4` and other that does not, so it would be nice of OP chose one. However, general ideas are similar: white castles long, black castles short, and they pawn-storm each other. Black often sacrifices a rook for `Nc3`, to increase power of their dark-squared bishop. If I was more versed in the Dragon, I would answer :). I think a reasonable answer is possible though.

Comment: @zscoder, it would be help if you provide some of your ideas, what do you know about the dragon so far? This information would help others answer.

Comment: I have trouble inputing 0-0. :(

Comment: @Akavall, Sicilian Dragon is one of the openings where move order is very important, especially in the opposite-side castling lines. So it's dangerous to give general ideas like pawn-storm and rook sac. Yes, you can say there are two main lines, one involving Bc4 and one not involving Bc4, but the theory of these lines is extremely vast. You could give a general idea for the lines after Be2, but Bc4 is too sharp a line to give general ideas for. One loss of tempo and you could be crushed (and then blame me for giving general ideas! :) ).

Comment: Oh, I play Bc4 :(

Comment: Actually, I realized that there's even more. There's Bc4 with castling queenside and there's no Bc4 but castling both kingside and queenside.

Comment: @zscoder, for castling are you using big O or zero? It should be big O.

Comment: @Wes, OK, fine. Fair point.

Comment: Oh, I used zero. No wonder. Thanks Akavall!

Answer (score 0):

**My personal opinion:**
If you are really annoyed of your opponents opening preparation of *early dragon* then just avoid it in the beginning. There is a friend of mine who crammed the dragon at length. I was extremely annoyed. To avoid the dragon I started to play Morra's Gambit. Morra's Gambit is quite effective. It can take your opponent out of the opening. You can try Morra Gambit if you are an attacking player otherwise do not go for it. You need to play quite sharp in Morra's Gambit. If you lose your tempo then the Gambit will go in vain and the opponent will get a clear advantage of 1 pawn.

**Short answer:**

If you want to deal with the position after `6...Bg7` then you will have to learn the theory. The main options are  `7.Bc4,Be2,f4,f3`.  Other option are `7.Bb5+`, even moves like `7.a3,a4`  or  `7.h3,h4` are playable. `7.h4` is quite attacking and `8.h5` can be sacrificed for a open file. `7.g3` is also playable but it seems like a dull move because `Bg2` won't be very effective because black's Night can soon jump at `g4`.

In `7.Be2 or Bc4` line sometimes after some moves there is an option of retreating the bishop on `f1`.

There is so much theory that a full fledged book can be written.

In some lines you may go for opposite castling but you will loose your small opening advantage. It will be still playable because the game will become highly tactical and attacking for both the sides. If you are good in tactics you can try this.

If you do not like very much Black's dark bishop on `g7` then you can double your bishop with Queen(`7.Qd2`) and force Black to trade the bishops. Again doing this will give up your opening advantage.

If you are not playing at GM level then small opening advantage doesn't matter. Infact the whole opening doesn't matter.

The **real answer** to your question is read a book of dragon variation and use latest stockfish engine to analyse different lines :-)